# Нужен способ получения случайных английских слов. Как лучше это реализовать?

Tags: c#, unity3d, словари

Делаю игру, развивающую скорость печать(знаю, такие уже есть). Понимаю, что нужен файл либо база данных слов, как именно это лучше реализовать, и где можно скачать подобные словари?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Реализация:

Самое простое, что приходит в голову это хранить слова в txt файле.

1. Загружаем строку из файла.
2. Разбиваем ее в зависимости от разделителя для слов, который был использован.
3. Складываем это все в массив и дальше пользуемся как угодно.

### Скачать:

Есть частотные словари, вот например такой http://www.wordfrequency.info/100k.asp

Answer (score 2):

Списки слов есть в интернете, и легко гуглятся. Поэтому вы можете подсчитать общее количество слов/строк в файле, и в нужный момент просто брать строку со случайным номером.

Небольшой трюк состоит в том, что обычно искать строку по номеру невозможно без предварительного чтения всех предыдущих строк. Чтобы обойти это, подсчитайте максимальную длину слова в вашем файле, и дополните все слова пробелами до этой максимальной ширины. Теперь ваши строки все одинакового размера (разумеется, если вы используете `Encoding.Unicode`, а не `Encoding.UTF8`: английские слова могут содержать символы вне ASCII), и вы можете просто найти смещение начала строки в файле.

Ну или если в вашем словаре несчастных 20 тысяч слов (размером со словарный запас Пушкина), можно не париться с оптимизацией хранения, и считать весь словарь в память один раз при старте программы.

Comment: я подумываю при загрузке читать весь файл в массив и потом уже все манипуляции проводить с массивом

Comment: @V.Salenko: Угу, мне это кажется самым адекватным решением.